# Biconditional in equivalence relation proof?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Not too sure how to approach this. Say I am given this:

All $x, y \in\mathbb{Z}, xRy \iff y = x + 6$ or $y = x - 6$

Question is to check whether this is an equivalence relation.

To approach this question, I presume I need to split into two cases due to $\iff$? For example:

1) $x, y \in\mathbb{Z}, xRy \Rightarrow y = x + 6$

2) $y = x - 6 \Rightarrow x, y \in\mathbb{Z}, xRy$

From here on, solve each of the above to make sure both get the same results - that is to prove reflexivity, symmetric and transitivity to conclude it is equivalence equation.

My confusion here is the use of $\iff$?. How does this affect how I find the 3 relations first? I haven't encounter $\iff$ before other than in logic.

Comment: No; that is the def of the relation $R$; you have to check that the three properties of an equiv relation hold. If so, you can conclude that $R$ is an equiv.

Comment: Thus, the first step is to check *reflexivity*: $xRx$.

Comment: Hi, I understand that I will need to find the three properties before I can conclude equivalence relation. I have updated my question to clarify the part which I do not understand. Hope you can have a read again, thanks.

Comment: The answer is the same; you have to **prove** that $R$ is an equiv rel; thus, you have to prove that the "specification" defining $R$ (the formula to the right of the biconditional) satisfies the three properties of an equiv rel. If Yes, then you can conclude that $R$ is an equiv rel.

Comment: The argument is: "**if** $R$ is refl and symm and trans, **then** $R$ is an equiv relation".

Comment: This means that the bicondition plays no role here? I just need to prove the right hand side and that's it?

Comment: I think I got it, the use of bicondition symbol seem to be typical for relation (my lecture notes do not show this symbol at all which was why I was confused). Should be able to crack this problem now. Thanks.

Comment: The role of the biconditional is only to define the "symbol" $R$. In "computer science" it is sometimes used: $R := \text { blah blah }$ for definitions. In other contexts sometimes: $R =_{def} \text { blah blah }$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biconditional here (and often) means that it's the *definition* of the given relation $R$. In other symbols, considering relations as sets of ordered pairs, it would be
$$R:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\, :\, y=x+6\,\text{ or }\, y=x-6\}\,.$$
Note that this relation is symmetric but is neither reflexive nor transitive.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the biconditional! Yes, I have the same results as you. I will mark this as solved.